# Slick carousel arrows: false removes the whole thing not just the arrows

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to remove the arrows from this carousel, 
I have tried using the

```
$('.slides').slick({
    arrows:false
});
```

however it just removes the whole carousel, not sure why this is?

Carousel from **[Slick Carouse](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)**

and using on **[Website](http://www.vestedutility.com.au/)**

Answer (score 0):

it was my .block div if i removed it in the css the carousel showed up, however it then messed up the heading not sure how the .block div messed it up. So instead I added div class=header-padding under my heading and adjusted the padding depending on the screen size it seams to work!

Answer (score 0):

I've Tried this

```
$(".yourSlickTarget button").remove();
```

Hope It Works ok with you